# a4j:included rich:dataTable negatively affects a4j:commandButton

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I have a JSF/RichFaces setup with an `index.jsp` which `a4j:include`s another piece of code which contains a `rich:dataTable`.

It initially renders fine, and selecting an item on the `index.jsp`'s dropDown list and clicking the 'Retrieve' `a4j:commandButton` uses the backing bean's `setChosen` method to do it's bidding on the back end.  The backing bean updates class members whose getters are then called by the model reading elements in a separate file `content.jsp` which is `a4j:include`d. My updated tabPanel appears.

I can see output in the eclipse console.  But when I hit the button again, nothing happens.  Nothing in the tomcat 6.0 log and nothing on the console.

**EDIT1**
Narrowing the problem down to my `content.jsp` file and not the above `index.jsp` code, I've found that a `rich:dataTable` element is the problem.  When I remove just this element from the `content.jsp`, I can reclick on the Retrieve button over and over and it reloads my tab panel.  As soon as I put it in, the first click is ok, and then the button will click, but nothing occurs and the button doesn't unclick back out.

The method that provides the `rich:dataTable` with data shouldn't be suspicious as it works at least the first time, but it only performs some xpath routines and returns a `ArrayList<MyDataList>`.

Given the edit, can anyone now suggest how to use `rich:dataTable` so that it doesn't cause any trouble?  The element is inside a `rich:tabPanel` which is inside an `h:form` but that is all.

Thanks

**EDIT2**:
In response to a commented request below, the following is the full affected code listing as brief as will reproduce the problem.  @Damo, please note the `a4j:commandButton` and `rich:dataTable` are in different files as the latter is in the jsp file which is `a4j:include`d.
Also note the `<%@ taglib uri=...` references have been removed from both files.

index.jsp:

```
<f:loadBundle basename="messages" var="msg" />

<f:view>
    <rich:page pageTitle="MyTitle" markupType="xhtml">
    <h:outputText id="setup" value="#{MyBacking.setup}" />
        <rich:toolBar height="35" itemSeparator="line">
            <rich:toolBarGroup location="left">
                <a4j:form>
                    <a4j:outputPanel id="panel">
                        <h:outputText style="text-align: center" value="Select " />
                        <h:selectOneMenu id="nodes" value="#{MyBacking.chosen}">
                            <f:selectItems value="#{MyBacking.nodes}" />
                        </h:selectOneMenu>
                        <a4j:commandButton value="Retrieve"
                            reRender="panel,contentPanel,currNode,lastOp"
                            onclick="this.disabled=true" oncomplete="this.disabled=false" />
                    </a4j:outputPanel>
                </a4j:form>
            </rich:toolBarGroup>
        </rich:toolBar>

        <rich:panel>
            <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="contentPanel">
                <a4j:include viewId="#{MyBacking.viewId}">
                    <f:param name="targetIdParam" value="content" />
                </a4j:include>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </rich:panel>
    </rich:page>
</f:view>
```

`a4j:include`d `content.jsp`:

```
<h:form id="myConfig">
    <rich:tabPanel switchType="client" rendered="true">
        <rich:tab styleClass="tab" label="Connections">
            <rich:dataTable onRowMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='#F1F1F1'"
                onRowMouseOut="this.style.backgroundColor='#{a4jSkin.tableBackgroundColor}'"
                cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0" var="item"
                value="#{MyBacking.DataList}">
                <rich:column style="text-align:center" width="150px">
                    <h:outputText styleClass="txtBold"
                        value="#{item.info}:#{item.other}" />
                </rich:column>
            </rich:dataTable>
        </rich:tab>
    </rich:tabPanel>
</h:form>
```

Thanks very much indeed for looking at this.

**EDIT3**
As requested, I've tried encapsulating the `a4j:include` within an `h:form`.  In order for the included content to avoid nesting an h:form, I replaced the enclosing `h:form` tag in `content.jsp` with an `h:panelGrid`.
When I reran this the second click on the `a4j:commandButton` still caused a hang, but I checked with firebug and a `POST http://localhost:8888/index.jsf 200 13ms` occurred but the response was empty.  Does this help?

Comment: check the firefox javascript console and the logs

Comment: post your page so that we can see the commandButton *and* the datatable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was to install a facelets jar.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335490/richfaces-richpanelmenu-stops-working-when-a4jincluded/2374298#2374298).

Answer (score 4):

I often experience this when I reRender commandButtons/Links.

Your a4j:form is in effect reRendering itself. Try changing it to something like this:

```
<a4j:form>
    <a4j:outputPanel id="panel">
        <h:outputText style="text-align: center" value="Select " />
        <h:selectOneMenu id="mySelect" value="#{MyBacking.chosen}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{MyBacking.myList}" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
    </a4j:outputPanel>
    <a4j:commandButton value="Retrieve" reRender="panel"/>
</a4j:form>
```

UPDATE: move your h:form to enclose the a4j:include. Pretty sure that it needs a form and of course you can't nest forms.

Comment: Good response, but it doesn't work.  If I use an a4j:outputPanel, could I not ignore the need for an a4j:form?

Comment: Interesting. The button was starting a cascade of backing bean work to do different things. I've narrowed it down so that it works as above fine unless the bean updates an element which is a4j:included into the above page with contains a `rich:dataTable`.  i don't even need to reRender the a4j:include to reveal the content of the include.  do i need faces-config.xml navigation content for a4j:included content? i'll ask another specific question about this.

Comment: Sorry Damo, I've unchecked the tick, as it was that or reask essentially the same question and get flamed.  I've not run the original code without the dataTable element so I guess it's possible I had two problems, but essentially I've still got the problem nonetheless.  Question has a new title.

Comment: Updated question to include `h:form` to no avail.