# Nesting h:form tags in RichFaces a4j:included content

Tags: jsf, richfaces

How is it possible to enclose ajax-related elements with `h:form` tags in a jsp file which I want to then `a4j:include` in another jsp file given the [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237863/a4jincluded-richdatatable-negatively-affects-a4jcommandbutton)  (EDIT 3) to fix another problem by enclosing my `a4j:include` in an `h:form` tag?

If my included code also has forms in that would suggest a nested form structure which will likely cause problems.  A solution to how to go about this would be greatly appreciated.

I'm creating a webapp which uses ajax components so there is no page to page navigation as such as I want everything in the same 'window'.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `<a4j:region>` instead of `<x:form>`. Nesting form is not recommended indeed.

Comment: I'll try it first thing. Thanks as always.