# How do I avoid using nested forms in Richfaces 4 + How do I use a4j:push in Richfaces 4?

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I'm using Richfaces 4 CR1 + JSF 2.0. And I have got two questions : 
 
1) I know nesting is not allowed in JSF. It just isn't.
Here's a use case - I have a master page which includes header.xhtml and footer.xhtml with

```
    <ui:include src="header.xhtml"/> 
    <h:form>
      <rich:tabPanel switchType="ajax"..>
        <rich:tab ..>
          <ui:include src="/includes/page1.xhtml" .../>
        </rich:tab>
        <rich:tab ..>
          <ui:include src="/includes/page2.xhtml" .../>
        </rich:tab>
     </rich:tabPanel>
  </h:form>
  <ui:include src="footer.xhtml" .../>
```

The `<rich:tabPanel ../>` needs to wrapped with a `<h:form.../>`. And since each of my tab is actually another xhtml page, some of them have controls like `<rich:togglePanel ../>` which ***also*** requires a `<h:form ../>` tag around it...!
So how do I handle this in the best possible way?

PS : I have referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363681/nesting-hform-tags-in-richfaces-a4jincluded-content) question and may be even my question's answer lies in `<a4j:region ../>`

2) How do I use `a4j:push` in Richfaces 4? The documentation is still in progress. The sample code is [here](http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/richfaces/branches/4.0.0.CR1/examples/push-demo/) but I couldn't understand the following line -

```
<a4j:push address="#{channelName}@chat" .. />
```

Any help with these two is greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers to above questions given by **[Max Katz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/297847/max-katz)** in an email chain were

1) Use a global form. When you submit, only the current active tab components will be processed

2) Max Katz, Ilya Shaikovsky and guys at Exadel/Richfaces were kind enough to publish a how-to on ajax:push [here](http://in.relation.to/18860.lace)

Can't thank them enough! :)

Comment: Hi Nikhil. I have the same issue as you had. What do you mean by a global form? Could you possibly post a quick snippet of your solution? Thanks

Comment: @Thomas, sorry I might be a little late. The above code remains the same, its just that the inner components in page1 and page2 should be wrapped in a4j:region. As far as components which need <h:form> are concerned, AFAIK in switchType ajax, the framework fails to take the outermost <h:form> as parent for these so two options available are 1) use alternate components, 2) change the switchType to server so that framework readily knows the parent of the inner components while generating view root tree.